# Empty variable when attempting to scrape web data using RVest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use Rvest to scrape a data point from:

https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-ftse-developed-europe-ex-uk-ucits-etf-eur-distributing/distributions

What I am attempting to capture is the "Yield As at close 30 Apr 2022" number which is 2.53%

I have attempted this using the following code

```
url <- "https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-ftse-developed-europe-ex-uk-ucits-etf-eur-distributing/distributions"

  url_read <- url %>%
    read_html()
  
  etf_Data <- url_read %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/ukd-app/ukd-pla-nav/div[1]/ukd-fund-detail/div[2]/ukd-distributions/dl/div[2]') %>%
    html_text()
```

however is is returning character(0).

Based on previous responses on SO I have tried to see if a passthrough query is required in the URL however my knowledge is fairly limited so have been unable to tell if it is required.

I have also tried

```
etf_Data <- url_read %>%
    html_element('.caption:contains("Yield As at close 30 Apr 2022") + .data') %>% html_text2()
```

and

```
etf_Data <- url_read %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/ukd-app/ukd-pla-nav/div[1]/ukd-fund-detail/div[2]/ukd-distributions/dl/div[2]') %>%
    html_table()
```

with the same response.

Any help you could provide would be appreciated.

Thanks
C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the data is loaded dynamically to the Page using JavaScript. You could work around this using `Rselenium`.

A much simpler solution is - with a slight modification of the Url - to request the data from the API:

```r
library(httr)

resp <- GET("https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/api/fund-detail/vanguard-ftse-developed-europe-ex-uk-ucits-etf-eur-distributing") %>% content()
yield <- resp$fundData$distributionHistory$yield[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. To help me expand my knowledge when inspecting a page how do I identify that the page is being loaded dynamically using JavaScript and where would I find the API Url?

Comment: @Robbo , when in inspect elements through your browser's dev.tools, take a look at actual page source too (or disable javascript for that site :)  ). In your cease the page source is quite bare and lacks all the elements you were requesting through rvest. You can hunt down API calls through network tab of dev.tools , being creative with search and filters helps to work though all that noise ('e.g while on network tab, search (ctrl+f) for "2.53" , go through results and repeat the search in Response and/or Preview pane - https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Oym.png )